# ImportError: No module name pyssh

Tags: server, python

I run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pexpect
```

On my Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS, I have both Python2.7 and Python3.1.3

I run this [script](http://goldb.org/sshpython.html) using python3.1.3 script.py, then python script.py but I get this error:

ImportError: No module name: pyssh

Why does this happen ?
After running the above command: will I be able to use pexpect both from python3.1.3 and python2.7 ? (i even guessed I have python3.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PySSH is a Python module for programmatically controlling ssh and scp.
>   NOTE: This project is no longer maintained. Please consider using
>   Paramiko (http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) instead.

Actually paramiko only works for python 2.x

[pexpect](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-pexpect) works with python3 but only with recent releases (14.04).

So to run your code, you have to stay with python2 unless you install the git master branch of paramiko which now [supports](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/README) python 3.2.

Comment: Is not it possible to run SSH with python 3.1.3 ?

Comment: the paramiko git repo [supports python3](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16#event-101929597), follow this [guide](http://pandu.poluan.info/blog/20140103-17/install-paramiko-python3-ubuntu1204/#comment-1278673476) to install this version

Comment: I decided to use Paramiko API. However, when I try to use it with Python3.1.3, I get this error message: no module named hashlib, and no module named md5. I installed zlib1g-dev (for hashlib) and purged/reinstalled Python3.1.3 but i get the same errors

Comment: Please try with python3.2 instead, the README file only mentions this version

Comment: The problem is that I am not allowed to develop in a Python version other than 3.1.3. I will check if there are not differences between 3.1.3 and 3.2 Python versions that can influence my existing software. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I decided to use telnet instead of SSH because I am not allowed to use an other Pythong version other than 3.1.3. Using telnet won't cause security problems for my software (i think) because I use only to connect from my host to VM machine.

Answer (score 0):

Download the debian package for pyssh from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyssh/files/latest/download?source=files) and then open a terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-terminal` and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i </path/to/the/deb/file>
```

and then retry running the script.

Comment: thank you. In fact, it is not a .deb file. I installed it. Now when I run python2.7 script.py  it works, but it does not work with python3.2 script.py and python3.1.3 script.py Why ?